# How can I refresh datasets/resources in the new Google BigQuery Web UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm creating tables via the Big Query command-line utility, but occasionally ad-hoc querying with the new web UI.  After creating a table via the CLI, how do I refresh the datasets/resources section in the new Google BigQuery Web UI so that I can see the newly-created table?  The old UI had a "refresh" drop-down menu item next to the dataset name.

I do not want to reload the entire webpage because it removes the text I have in the query editor and requires me to search for the tables again.  I would ideally like to just refresh the list of datasets in the "Resources" section.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The BigQuery team is already considering the possibility to add the "Refresh" button that was available in the Classic UI, to the New UI, in order to be able to reload the datasets and tables on a project without the need of reloading the entire page, as is needed now in order to see all the changes in the BigQuery project.

There are already several public Feature Requests available in the Public Issue Tracker, but let me share with you [the one which is receiving more attention from other users](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112586996). Feel free to "*star*" this issue in order to highlight its importance and leave a comment if you feel like there is anything relevant you want to add to the discussion.

Rest assured that this topic is already being discussed internally and the BigQuery team will update the public Feature Request whenever there is any relevant information to be shared with the users.

Comment: 2 years later and there's still no sign of a refresh button.

Comment: +1 on the observation that 2 years later, and this SIMPLE feature is sorely missing.  One wonders what the BQ developers are so busy with, as not to be able to address this simple but fundamental need....

Comment: 2 years & 5 months now. Still waiting.

Comment: Just a note that the issue you linked to is now marked as dupe and [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122326196) is now the main one.

Comment: Excited to see what ~3.5 years of refresh button dev looks like.

Comment: Still waiting. This is crazy

Comment: ....  . . . 

Answer (score 8):

I have found a workaround for anyone still waiting.

If you click the search box in the project/dataset "Explorer" sidebar, then press enter, it will refresh the list.

This one... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uce18.png

Comment: This works. Thank you! What joke that there is no refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible. From the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#February_09_2023):

> Cloud console updates: In the Explorer pane, you can now refresh the contents of a resource (project or dataset). To refresh the contents of a resource, click more_vert View actions, and then click Refresh contents.

[image]

Comment: Note that "Refresh contents" is only available when "Show starred only" is NOT used